# What is touristd?

Tags: macos, daemons

In macOS Sierra there is a new daemon `touristd`.

What is `touristd` and what is it used for?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## What is `touristd` responsible for?

`touristd` is responsible for displaying a **New to Mac?** notification roughly after 5-10 minutes using macOS Sierra for the first time.

[image: 'New to Mac?' notification]

After you click on **Show** it will open the [What's New in macOS](http://help.apple.com/macOS/Sierra/WN/#/intro-WN) page in Safari.

There is a preference file that gets created/modified after dismissing or activating the notification.

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.touristd.plist.
```

#### Where can you find it?

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Tourist.framework/Versions/A/Resources/touristd
```

Comment: I just noticed that `touristd` was downloading something on my Mac long after macOS Sierra has been activated. (using 10.3.3 at the moment). Also it has 1:17,53 of CPU-time. There must be more jobs for this daemon than just the **New to Mac?** notification.

Comment: Yes, it can display different Apple tours depending on OS and device.  You can try to run `touristd --help` (with full path) to get some hint. This is also discussed in [this blog post](https://carlashley.com/2016/10/19/com-apple-touristd/).

Comment: I was looking at my recent Time Machine contents, and noticed that yesterday all the files (mostly icon files) in `~admin/Library/Application Support/com.apple.touristd` were updated. I'm running High Sierra.