# What is the touristd process doing when it downloads ~14MB on each boot?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, daemons

I've noticed on my MacBook Air (early 2015 edition, macOS 10.13.3) that there is a certain 'touristd' process that launches when I turn on the computer, downloads about 14.2MB of data, then exits.

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294291/what-is-touristd) already discusses that the process is for the "New to Mac?" tour, and although a comment on the answer also notes the downloading, no answer appears to be offered. Here's a screenshot I managed to capture just before it exited, from Activity Monitor:

[image]

It went up to 14.2 MB a second later, then disappeared from the list, but I couldn't capture it fast enough.

Does anyone know what this process is doing and what it's downloading on every boot?